# How to Implement Token Generation and Validation for Intranet-based CSR Access to an Internet User Portal?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, asp.net-web-api, oauth

I'm developing a system where Customer Service Representatives (CSRs) on our intranet can view user data. One of the features I'm aiming to implement is to allow the CSR to log into an internet-based user portal on behalf of users who are on a call, with just the click of a button. This is to assist users more effectively.

Currently, our user portal (which is on the internet) authenticates users based on their user ID and password, and upon successful authentication, an OAuth token is generated. I'd like to replicate a similar token-based authentication system for CSRs when they click on the button from the intranet application.

Here are my specific questions:

How can I securely generate and validate tokens for CSRs from the intranet to access the internet-based user portal without compromising the security of the user accounts?
Are there best practices or recommended patterns for this kind of "impersonation" or "on-behalf-of" authentication, especially when bridging intranet to internet?
Given that we're using OAuth for our regular users on the internet-based portal, is there a way to extend or modify this system to cater to the CSR's use case on the intranet?
Any guidance or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Direct OAuth Implementation for CSRs: I initially considered using the same OAuth mechanism for CSRs as we do for regular users. However, I quickly realized that this might not be feasible since the CSR application is on our intranet, and the user portal is on the internet.

Static Token for CSRs: I thought about generating a static token for CSRs that would allow them to access the user portal. But this seemed insecure as it would give CSRs unrestricted access to any user account.

Temporary Token Generation: I also explored the idea of generating a temporary token for CSRs whenever they need to access the user portal. This token would expire after a short duration. However, I'm unsure about the security implications and the best way to implement this.

What I was expecting:

I was hoping to find a seamless and secure method that would allow CSRs to access the user portal from our intranet application with the click of a button. The solution should ensure that CSRs can only access the specific user account they are assisting, and there should be no potential for misuse. Additionally, the method should be robust enough to handle any network discrepancies between the intranet and the internet.